# Definition of cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have some problem understanding some aspects of the definition of an arbitrary cartesian product. What I have so far:

> Let $\mathscr{A} = (A_s)_{s \in S}$ be a collection of sets. The
>   cartesian product of the collection $\mathscr{A}$ is: $$\begin{align}
>  \prod\mathscr{A} = \prod_{s \in S}A_s &:= \left\{ f: \mathscr{A} \to
>  \bigcup_{s \in S}A_s \mid f(A) \in A, \, \forall\, A \in \mathscr{A} 
>  \right\} \\ &= \left\{ f: S \to \bigcup_{s \in S}A_s \mid f(s) \in
>  A_s, \forall\, s \in S \right\}\end{align}.
> $$If $\mathscr{A} =\{A_1, \ldots A_n\}$, we will write $\prod\mathscr{A} = A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$.

By my understanding, I get that if $A$ and $B$ are sets, we have: $$A \times B = \{f: \{A,B\} \to A \cup B\mid f(A) \in A \text{ and }f(B) \in B\}$$

I am asked, then, to prove that given sets $A,B$ and $C$, we have $A \times(B \cup C) = (A \times B)\cup(A \times C)$.

**Doubt 1:** How can I make the comparison if the domains of the elements on both sides are different? It does not make any sense at all.

Suppose I don't care and go on: If $f \in A \times(B \cup C)$, then $f(A) \in A$ and $f(B \cup C) \in B \cup C$. I would think then, that if $f(B \cup C) \in B$, then $f \in A \times B$, and if $f(B \cup C)\in C$, we have $f \in A \times C$, so anyway we have the inclusion $\subseteq$. On the other hand, it suffices to prove that $A \times B \subseteq A \times(B \cup C)$ (WLOG). If $f \in A \times B$, then $f(A) \in A$ and $f(B) \in B \subset B \cup C$ and so $f \in A \times(B \cup C)$. I am not comfortable at all with this, since I do not have a rigorous definition of a functions, and the most formal one I know is that $f : A \to B$ is a function if $f \in A \times B$ satisfies blah blah blah. It is circular.

Up next I am asked to prove that $A \times B = A \times C$ and $A \neq \varnothing$, then $B = C$. My idea consists mainly of the following: since $A \neq \varnothing$, then exists $a \in A$. Take $x \in B$, if I prove that $x \in C$ then I am done. Define $f:\{A, B\}\to A \cup B$ by setting $f(A) = a \in A$ and $f(B) = x \in B$. This way $f \in A \times B$, and by hypothesis $f \in A \times C$. I don't know how to give the next step in this argument.

**Doubt 2:** Can't I just say that if $f \in A \times B = A \times B$ implies $\{A,B\}=\{A,C\}$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$, based on domains and codomains, and from there try to get $B = C$?

I probably can tackle these problems on my on, if I can understand the definitions correctly, but all of this is very cloudy and I need some help understanding. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product?rq=1) question, but it **doesn't** address my specific problems here.

Comment: As you can see in the post referenced in you comment, the finite case (ordered n-uples) and the infinite one (functions) do not define the same set but "different sets, although there is a canonical bijection between them."

Comment: The second of the two definitions of the Cartesian product, in which an element of the product is a function on the same index set $S$ as the family $\mathscr{A}$, looks fine, but I can't make sense of the first definition; and it seems to be this one that's causing the problem.  Where did it come from?

Comment: I am taking a general topology course, and most people over here have little practice with elementary set theory, so the TA made a list of exercises so we could practice. [Here](https://linux.ime.usp.br/~phmacedo/lista1-topo2015.pdf) it is, in the last page (in Portuguese, but I think you can make sense of it). The exercises are not worth any credit, in case that it matters, they are just for practice. I could ask the TA himself, but I will only see him next wednesday, and I don't want to bother him with emails in the midtime. And also I prefer asking stuff here (personal taste).

Comment: (Excuse delay, but I didn't get an "@" notification of your reply.) Your version of the first definition is, if anything, clearer than the one in the PDF!  But it also looks, from the appearance of Exercises 16 and 17, as if you could safely ignore the first of the two definitions for the time being, use the second definition when doing the exercises, and ask the TA to explain the first definition when you see him again. For what it's worth, the first definition looks to me like the definition of a "choice function", as seen in some versions of the Axiom of Choice, but it's odd to see it here.

Comment: @Calum Yes, I thought so too, about the choice function.. I ended up using the definition of the product via ordered pairs, anyway. I'll ask the TA. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, The main reason the first definition is confusing I think is that there is a somewhat confusing definition of $\mathscr{A}$. If you don't bother with the notation at the bottom and just look at the notation at the top, you can see that $\mathscr{A}$ is actually a collection of sets indexed by $S$. This means that it's just a function from $S$ onto the set containing the $A_s$'s. That you can read as a set of ordered pairs $<s,A>$ where $s\in S$. Then a function from these pairs is essentially the same as indexing by $S$ again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem that we encounter is in the first definition. Namely, it does not work if $(A_s)_{s\in S}$ contains duplicates. It therefore cannot be used to define one of the most common examples of the Cartesian product, namely $A^n$.

As to your problem with the circularity in the definition of a function, I think it's mostly a matter of recognising that the definition of the *binary* Cartesian product is a case treated separately—defined in the usual way: ordered pairs via Kuratowski's definition, then setting:

$$A \times B := \{(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}$$

which is proved to exist in $\sf ZF$ in many, many places. It is correct that this is not equal to $\prod \{A, B\}$, and this obfuscation of the distinction between *binary* and *arbitrary* Cartesian product is a weak point in the exposition.

Next, we also have the definition of a function, $f$ is a **function** iff:

- $f \subseteq A \times B$;
- $(a,b) \in f$ and $(a,c) \in f$ imply $b= c$.

Then, the notation "$f: A \to B$" means:

- $\forall a: (a \in A \iff \exists b \in B: (a,b) \in f)$;
- $\forall b: \exists a \in A: (a,b) \in f \implies b \in B$.

---

With that all out of the way, we can get to the definition of the Cartesian product proper. To avoid confusion, let us write $\prod \{A, B\}$ instead of $A \times B$ in addressing "binary arbitrary Cartesian products". Let us also agree that for such finite products, the indexing set is $\{1\ldots n\}$.

These presuppositions having been specified, we can see that:

\begin{align*}
\prod \{A,B \cup C\} &= \left\{f: \{1,2\} \to A \cup B \cup C \middle\vert f(1) \in A, f(2) \in B \cup C \right\}\\
\prod \{A,B\} &= \left\{f: \{1,2\} \to A \cup B \middle\vert f(1) \in A, f(2) \in B \right\}\\
\prod \{A,C\} &= \left\{f: \{1,2\} \to A \cup C \middle\vert f(1) \in A, f(2) \in C \right\}\\
\end{align*}

Now that we have cut through the complicated language, I trust that you can see that the asserted equation does make sense, and indeed can prove it yourself.

---

Lastly, your second doubt concerns the first definition, which as said is problematic because it is not general enough.

Your proof is good, and it can be concluded from $f \in A \times C$ that $f(2) \in C$, and by construction $f(2) = x$; hence $x \in C$. Swapping the roles of $B$ and $C$ yields the reverse inclusion, proving equality.

Comment: I find this detailed enough and very helpful. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: You're very welcome :).