# Does all collection of sets have an index-set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this form of the axiom of choice:

> Suppose that C is a collection of nonempty sets. Then thre exists a
>   function $f:C\rightarrow \cup_{A\in C}A$ such that $f(A)\in A$ for
>   each $A \in C$.

I have this exercise:

> Show that the axiom of choice is equivalent to the following statement
>   : If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is any indexed collection of nonempty sets,
>   then $\times _{i \in I}A_i \ne \emptyset$.

Now, having the axiom of choice, I think it is ok to show that the second statement follows from the first one. But assuming the second statement, and also assuming that we have the collection C, I have a little trouble showing the axiom of choice. Because I can not just assume that I can index the sets?, and create an index set?, or can I?

Comment: Collection of all sets? *Takes cover.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can every set be written as a family?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179568/can-every-set-be-written-as-a-family)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a set $C$ which you want to index as $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, the natural choice would be to set $I=C$ and $A_c=c$. There's no rule that says you can't, and it certainly functions. (And one would only tend to care about the fact that an indexed collection is different from a set if they wished to include some members multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

An indexing of a set $C$ over some index set $I$ is a mapping
$$
f : I \rightarrow C, \quad i \mapsto c_i
$$
There is at least such index set $I$ and mapping $f$: we simply pick $I := C$ and let $f$ be the identity:
$$
f : C \rightarrow C, \quad i \mapsto i
.
$$