# Indexed System of Sets Proof Explanation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, infinite-product

[image]

Proof:

[image]

1. I'm not sure what $f_i$ is. is $f_i$ an ordered pair or an element
   of the codomain of f or what else?
2. Since f is a function on I, is I the codomain or domain of function
   f?
3. What is I?
   [image]

   4. What does the exponentiation or multiplication of sets yield? Is the exponentiation or multiplication of sets the same thing as doing the infinite or n-ary cartesian product?

---

Ignore the background below if you know what we're talking about:

[image]

Comment: $f_i$ is the value that $f$ take on when applied to $i$, and can also be written as $f(i)$. $(i,s_i) \in f$ means $f(i) = s_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: $f\subset I\times \cup_{i \in I}S_i$ means that $I$ is domain and $\cup_{i \in I}S_i$ is codomain. $f_i\in S_i$, so $f_i$ is an element of codomain. Moreover, $f(i)=f_i$ from definition. It is true, that $(i, f_i) \in f$, but in proof there is different notation, namely $(i, s_i) \in f$. I admit this notation is somewhat confusing.

It is helpful to start from beginning and carefully build things up. First of all $I$ is an arbitrary nonempty set. Then there is some auxiliary nonempty set of sets (aka family of sets) call it $X$. Now we need to fix some function $\Phi$ with domain $I$ and codomain $X$, thus $\Phi:I\to X$. In set language $\Phi=\{(i,x):i\in I ,x\in X \}$. Looks familiar? Observe, that if we take $X:=\{ S_i:i\in I\}$ and define $\Phi(i):=S_i$, then $\Phi=S$. It can be helpful to look at the case when $I=\{1,..,n\}$, and $|X|=m$ is also finite. Fix $\Phi: \{1,..,n\}\to X$, if $\Phi$ is surjection (so $n\geq m$), all elements of $X$ can be listed (probably many times) $X=\{\Phi(1),..,\Phi(n)\}$. Now take $X_i:=\Phi(i)$. For finitary product there is no need to introduce all that stuff, just simple induction:

- $X_1\times X_2=\widehat\prod_{i=1}^2X_i=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1\in X_1,x_2\in X_2\}$
- $\widehat\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=(\widehat\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i)\times X_n$

(There should be big "$\times$" sign instead of $\widehat\prod$, like [$\textbf{here}$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28162).)
What is important, in finitary case induction based definition is equivalent to the "functional" one (there is cannonical bijection):

- $\Pi_{i=1}^nX_i=\{f:f\ is\ a\ function\ on\ \{1..n\}\ and\ f(i)\in X_i\}$

It is helpful to see what is inside though:

$$\widehat\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\{(x_1,..,x_n):x_i\in X_i\}$$
$$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\{\{(1,x_1),..,(n,x_n)\}:x_i\in X_i\}$$

If induction based product is so simple, couldn't it be extended to arbitrary indexing set? It cannot and [$\underline{\textbf{here}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product) is why.

Exponent analogy to numbers (or more general cardinals) is that $|\{f:\ f\subset A\times B ,\ f\ is \ function\}|=|B|^{|A|}$, see [$\underline{\textbf{here}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223240/how-many-distinct-functions-can-be-defined-from-set-a-to-b).

Comment: Is $$\widehat\prod_{i=1}^nX_i=\{(x_1,..,x_n):x_i\in X_i\}$$ a set that has only one element, a n-tuple whose coordinates are all the elements in the range of the function psi? The tuple ($x_1,...x_n$): $x_i \in X_i$ looks like a vector $\in R^{|X|}$

Comment: What's the difference between 
$$\widehat\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$$ and
$$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$$? What difference does the carrot's presence versus absence  above the product sign make? Why is the n on edge of the carot or roof of the product on the former and not on the latter? @Przemek

Comment: I've put carrot to distinguish between two definitions. It isn't standard notation. Placement of $n$ is typographical issue of $\LaTeX$. In finitary case $n$-ary cartesian product could be stated as set of $n$-tuples. Now it boils down to definition of tuple: in first example ($\widehat\prod$) tuple is defined as [$\underline{\textbf{nested ordered pair}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_nested_ordered_pairs) $(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)$, in second ($\prod$) [$\underline{\textbf{as a function}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_functions) $(a,b,c)=\{(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)\}$.

Comment: Your intuition about vector space is almost correct. For $X_1=..=X_n=\mathbb{R}$, $\ X_1^n=\mathbb{R}^n=\{(x_1,..,x_n):x_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$. But in this context $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply set of $n$-tuples without vector space structure (e.g. adding vectors or multiplying by scalar).

Comment: Can you give me a finite example of the "nested ordered pair" and the infinite product (the pi looking thing)  "as a function (a,b,c)"? based on some concrete finite example of $S_i$ aka the "
indexed system of sets"? I'm having a hard time understanding the infinite general idea, so I was wondering whether you could give me a finite example or give me a specific indexed system of sets and then compute its infinite product and the "nested ordered pair" and "in second" pi-looking thing "as a function ..... (a,b,c).... @Przemek and show the proof is trivially true for that specific case.

Comment: HELLO @PRZEMEK....

Comment: I am confused, because I've already put an example of tuples and links to Wikipedia that discuss it in more detail. There was also a link to another SE question that should in my opinion shed some light ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product)). This topic is pretty tough at first sight (it was to me also), but after some time you'll hopefully find it meaningfull. Be sure you are familiar with cartesian-based definition of a function:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition.

Comment: There are examples:

$S_i=\{1..i\},\ i\in \mathbb{N}_+ $

$\widehat\prod_{i=1}^3S_i=\{((1,1),1),((1,1),2),((1,1),3),((1,2),1),((1,2),2),((1,2),3)\}$

$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}S_i=\{\{(1,a_1),(2,a_2),..\}:a_j\in S_j,\ j=1,2,3...\}=\{\{(1,a_1),(2,a_2),..\}:a_j\leq j,\ j=1,2,3...\}$