# Infinite cartesian product of singletons

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have infinitely many different singleton sets. If you took the infinite cartesian product of all your singleton sets, would the result be one giant ordered pair? Would it matter whether you had countably or uncountably infinite many singletons?

Comment: The answer depends on how you define "infinite cartesian product".

Comment: @Holo The OP asks "cartesian product of all *your singleton sets" [emphasis mine]. It's not a cartesian product of the entire class of singleton sets, it's the cartesian product of a particular set of singleton sets.

Comment: @Acccumulation , I see, noted, but [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product) is still relevant, OP, you should read that definition

Comment: @EthanBolker are there different ways to define an infinite cartesian product?

Comment: @J.P.Escarcega: If you know one definition, why not reveal what it is instead of playing games?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It may be genuine surprise, rather than game-playing.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Granted, I can think of only one too. But my suspicion is that the OP knows (or knew) _no_ definition of infinite cartesian product. At least, if they know one where speaking about "one giant ordered pair" makes sense, this definition would be news to me and I'd be interesting in hearing it ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's why I commented as I did. The single answer (so far) uses the standard definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result would be a set of one element: a fixed function, essentially. 
If the singletons are $\{a_i\}$ for $i \in I$, $I$ being some index set, then:

$$\prod_{i \in I} \{a_i\} = \{f\}$$ where $f: I \to \{a_i : i \in I\}$ is defined by $f(i) = a_i$.

So one element regardless of the size of $I$ (countable, finite, uncountable..)