# Understanding the definition of infinite Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

This is the first time I have come across the following definition for the infinite Cartesian product. I *somewhat* understand it, however, below I have pointed out where I am getting confused.

Definition for the infinite Cartesian product:

$$\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{X}_i = \{f: \operatorname{dom}(f) = \mathbb{N} \wedge
\forall i, f(i) \in \mathbb{X}_i\}.$$

Here is where I am getting confused. Define the following:

$$\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \{(x,y): x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge y \in \mathbb{R}\} \quad (i)$$

$$\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \prod_{i=1}^2\mathbb{R}_i = \{f: \operatorname{dom}(f) = \{1,2\} \wedge f(1) \in \mathbb{R}, f(2) \in \mathbb{R}\} \quad (ii)$$

Here is where I am getting confused. Lets say you want to write "express" the point where $x = 5$ and $y = \pi$, then using $(i)$ you would simply write $(5,\pi)$. How would you express the same for $(ii)$? In other words, I am just not sure how you would represent the same point using $(ii)$. I know that a function is, itself, a set.

Comment: See [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product)

Comment: Each element of the product is an $\infty$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ where the $i$-th element belongs to set $X_i$.

Comment: The case is similar to $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ where the elements a pairs $(r_1,r_2)$ where $r_i \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand the more elementary definition, that is, the $(i)$ definition I listed. However, I am just confused on how you would represent, say the point $(5, \pi)$ using $(ii)$.

Comment: The sets $X^2$ and $X\times X$ are *not identical* but there's a natural bijection between them: a function $f:\{0,1\}\to X$ corresponds to the pair $(f(0),\,f(1))$.

Comment: @Berci so $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ are not identical?

Comment: The "point" in (ii) is a function $f : \{ 1,2 \} \to \mathbb R$, where $f(1)=5$ and $f(2)= \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are confused in here is notations. $f$ in this definition is a *coordinate function*: it maps coordinate index to the corresponding value, and so each function $f$ represents a single point in a product set.

For example, point $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is exactly the function $f : \{1,2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1) = x_1$ and $f(2) = x_2$ (point $(5,\pi)$ may be represented as a such function $f$ with $f(1) = 5$ and $f(2) = \pi$).

One of the reasons for using such notation is that it could be easily generalised to any number of coordinates (including infinity) – all you need is just expand the domain of $f$. Take a look to the definition of infinite Cartesian product written using coordinates (like in $(i)$):
$$
\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{X}_i = \{(x_1, x_2, \dots) \wedge
\forall i, x_i \in \mathbb{X}_i\}.
$$
It contains expression $(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ which is, in a sense, *informal*: it uses notation for points with *finite* count of coordinates (where coordinates are represented directly), for points with *infinite* number of coordinates (which are, actually, the infinite sequences). Using notation with coordinate functions gives you much more formal and explicit way to describe such objects; take a look at the [formal definition of sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Definition), which uses the same construction.

Comment: Thank you! So, in essence, points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented as $(f(1), f(2))$ where $f(1) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(2) \in \mathbb{R}$, which is simply $(ii)$, correct?

Comment: @Dalton yes, sure, think about it as a just different notation for $(x_1, x_2)$

Comment: And, is $(ii)$ a set of a single function or a set of functions?

Comment: @Dalton $(ii)$ is a set of functions, where each function represents point $\mathbb{R}^2$