# Question about the equivalence of two definitions of Cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

I first learned about the Cartesian product as ordered pairs, but soon when we need to get the infinite Cartesian product, we regard it as mapping. I.e.$\prod U_i(i \in I)$= $(f:I \longrightarrow \cup_{i \ in I} U_i \wedge f(i)\in U_{i})$. I know that in essence, they are talking about the same thing, but how can a mapping be equivalent to ordered pairs? It is quite confusing.

My question is

> Why a set of mappings is equivalent to a set of ordered pairs?

[Definition of the Infinite Cartesian Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195517/definition-of-the-infinite-cartesian-product) fully solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordered pair $(x,y)\in E^2$ can be identified to the mapping $\{0,1\}\to E,\;0\mapsto x,\;1\mapsto y.$

Comment: In computer science, this is similar to having a pair of pointers to 2 objects, instead of having a pair of objects.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But when proving for example $(A\cap B) x (C \cap D)=(A x C) \cap (B x D)$, the ‘mapping’ definition seems unreachable

Comment: $$\left[(f(0)\in A\cap B)\land(f(1)\in C\cap D)\right]\Leftrightarrow\left[\left(f(0)\in A\land (f(1)\in C)\right)\land\left(f(0)\in B\land (f(1)\in D)\right)\right].$$